# Laravel : failed to open stream: Success _ error in auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i use laravel 5.6

i run below command :

```
php artisan make:auth
```

After registration in http://localhost:8000/register, I will encounter the following error :

```
 failed to open stream: Success
```

or after login in http://localhost:8000/login , I will encounter the following error :

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Thanks your help

Comment: Please try to clear the cache like this `php artisan cache:clear` or submit more info

Comment: There's probably a stack trace associated with those errors somewhere. That should help

Comment: @Jagjeet Singh i run this command but ...

Comment: @MostafaNorzade what happen :|

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. First thing is to clear the cache using this command:`php artisan cache:clear`.
2. Then regenerate classes that need in your project using this command:`composer dump-autoload -o`.
3. Update project using: `composer update`
4. Rollback the migrations using: `php artisan migrate:rollback`

Comment: Yeees . ofcorse then top command , i run `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

I Got this error & Solved by following commands.

> php artisan cache:clear
>
> composer dump-autoload -o
>
> composer update